# Karma Jasmine tests all fail after integrating ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a lot of tests in this app that were passing, but after integrating ui-router, every one of them fails.  I am getting errors like `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation')`.  and `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$rootScope.$digest')`.  Anything that gets injected in the tests no longer works once I do the integration.

The tests only fail if I inject the `$stateProvider, $stateParams or $urlRouteProvider`.  If I don't inject those, then they pass.

Is there some sort of configuration that I need?  Does anyone know why all of a sudden all of the previous injections are non-existent?

**Error Example**

```
forEach@app/vendor/angular/angular.js:403:24
loadModules@app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4880:12
createInjector@app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4802:30
WorkFn@app/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3163:60
app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4921:53
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$rootScope.$digest') in app/core/test/sideBarDirTest.js (line 63)
app/core/test/sideBarDirTest.js:63:23
```

**Karma Config**

```
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'app/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'app/vendor/angular/angular.js',
        'app/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'app/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'app/core/app.js',
        'app/core/envConfig.js',
        'app/core/sideBarDir.js',
        'app/core/app.js',
        'app/core/test/*.js',
        '**!/!*.html',
        {pattern: 'app/core/**/*.json', watched: true, served: true, included: false}
    ],
    exclude: [
        'app.js',
        '**/gulpfile.js'
    ],
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage', 'junit'],
    preprocessors: {
        'app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
        'app/core/**/!(*Test|*test).js': 'coverage',
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        stripPrefix: 'app/',
        moduleName: 'html'
    },

    junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'coverage/test-results.xml',
        suite: ''
    },

    coverageReporter: {
        type: 'lcov',
        dir: 'coverage/'
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    captureTimeout: 10000,
    singleRun: true
```

Comment: in your app used for karma testing have you listed `ngMock` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes I am.  When I was using ngRoute there was no problem.

Comment: Do you depend on any real http requests in your tests?

Comment: Yea I have every type of REST http request there is at some point.

Comment: When I had to integrate a mix of real and mocked http requests, I had to integrate the advice from this article to get it to work. It might help you: http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/16/unit-test-http-ngmock-passthrough/

Comment: @hughes thanks for the help, but my issue was with the error messages that were being produced.  PhantomJS wasn't telling me what the actual problem was. Switching to Chrome got me back on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the root cause was just some missing modules.  It seems as though my integration of ui-router required more files to be added to karma config than I thought.

When I asked this question, the error messages were very basic and that was what caused my headache. I fixed this problem by using Chrome as the browser to test with in the Karma config.  This switch immediately showed me the issue.  Apparently PhantomJS strips out/doesn't add the juicy parts of the error message(read: the actual Angular error).

So if you are randomly failing every test that used to pass, then I suggest that you switch to the Chrome browser to see if you aren't getting everything.

Comment: Using Chrome runner is really helpful for debugging. Not sure if the actual question is solvable at all though